# Is it possible to access the sub-types for the Google Places API?

Tags: google-places-api

When using the Yelp API they provide categories (ie Restaurants) and then also a long list of subcategories for that category (ie Italian, Mexican, Japanese, etc.).

It seems like this is not possible for the Google Places API because on their developers [website](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7878) they only list the broad categories. However, I know that subcategories do exist because they show up if you search for them. So is there any way to pull a list of the available subcategories that Google uses?